# Late bound resolution; runtime errors could occur and Implicit conversion from Object to 1-dimensional array of Byte Warning

Tags: vb.net

First i don't want to change the set of Option Explicit.

I've been trying to solve these warnings depending on the answers here, there are too many similar questions but no answer did work or i couldn't understand better. so any help would be appreciated. my code is

```
            If bs(m.ToArray).Contains(spl) Then
                Dim a As Array = fx(m.ToArray, spl)
                RaiseEvent data(a(0))
                m.Dispose
                m = New MemoryStream
                If a.Length = 2 Then
                    m.Write(a(1), 0, a(1).Length)
                    Thread.Sleep(1)
                    GoTo rr
                End If
            End If
```

and the fx function is

```
Public Function fx(b As Byte(), spl As String) As Array
    Dim l As New List(Of Byte())
    Dim m As New MemoryStream
    Dim mm As New MemoryStream
    Dim s As String() = Split(bs(b), spl)
    m.Write(b, 0, s(0).Length)
    mm.Write(b, s(0).Length + spl.Length, b.Length - (s(0).Length + spl.Length))
    l.Add(m.ToArray)
    l.Add(mm.ToArray)
    m.Dispose()
    mm.Dispose()
    Return l.ToArray
End Function
```

the errors are on the `a(0)` and `a(1)`, please any help would be appreciated and not a simple solution, i want to understand why this happens and how to avoid it
thank you in advanced.

Comment: The mem stream overload you are using is defined as `Write(buffer() As Byte, offset As Integer, count As Integer)`.  so the first argument is wrong (an array element <> array) and a System Array can only hold `Object` and Object <> Byte().  You have the wrong data types.  (and has little to do with Option Explicit)

Comment: @Plutonix ok i get it but how that would be a warning and not an error? and can i cast it to solve these warnings or do i have to change what the `fx` function returns?

Comment: It *is* an error but you may have VS configured to demote it to a warning.  Instead of casting, make it the right type at the outset: define `fx` to return `Byte()`

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I did VB.NET, but I think your problem is about using Array. I'm fairly positive that ToArray returns Byte(), not Array.

Array is a base class for all specific .NET array types, like int16, int32 and so on. You should only be using Array if using common functionality, like retrieving array bounds, or activator/reflection.

Code examples for Array class:
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array(v=vs.110).aspx

Proper use of arrays:
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/wak0wfyt.aspx

Side note regarding memory streams, it's best to use the [Using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) approach, otherwise an uncaught exception may result in memory leaks. Another good thing for you is reducing your lines of code, as you don't need to Dispose with Using, and it makes your code better visually structured (and optimizes scope/visibility).